# I can't turn off the axes of my plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, random-walk

I am writing code for a random walk model, and I use `plt.axes().get_xaxis().set_visible(False)` to hide the axes but when I run the program the plot still shows both axes.
Here is what I wrote:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from random_walk import RandomWalk

# Keep making random walks, as long as the program is active
while True:
    rw = RandomWalk()
    rw.fill_walk()

    point_numbers = list(range(rw.num_points))
    plt.scatter(rw.x_values, rw.y_values, c=point_numbers, cmap=plt.cm.Blues, edgecolors='none', s=10)

    # Emphasize the first and last points.
    plt.scatter(0, 0, c='green', edgecolors='none', s=50)
    plt.scatter(rw.x_values[-1], rw.y_values[-1], c='red', s=50)

    # Remove the axes.
    plt.axes().get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    plt.axes().get_yaxis().set_visible(False)    

    plt.show()

    keep_running = input("Make another walk? (y/n): ")
    if keep_running == 'n':
        break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `plt.gca().get_xaxis().set_visible(False)` instead of `plt.axes().get_xaxis().set_visible(False)`.

Here is a code example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.plot(np.random.random(1000))
plt.gca().get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
```

This short code will return:

[image]

Comment: Right Thank you very much

Comment: @Pedrolopez_e if it helped, mark it as an answer.